# partial.lenses: how to use asynchronous operations in optics with L.collect?

Tags: node.js, partial-lenses

I understand that [partial.lenses](https://github.com/calmm-js/partial.lenses) isn't necessarily the best solution to the following problem and that's besides the point in this question. I was trying to list files from a directory using [L.collect](https://github.com/calmm-js/partial.lenses#l-collect) from the partial.lenses library. Goal is just to get a flattened array of file names.

Problem: instead of using [fs.readdirSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path_options) I would like to make use of asynchronous, Promise returning versions of the Node's fs API, in my optics.

The following would be the promisified version of the readdir:

```
const util = require('util')
const fs = require('fs')
const readdirAsync = util.promisify(fs.readdir)
```

Below is the actual implementation. I would like to know how I can replace the synchronous `fs.readdirSync` in the `readdir` function with an asynchronous version.

```
const L = require("partial.lenses")
const fs = require("fs")
const path = require("path")
const _ = require("lodash")

const basePath = path.basename(`${__dirname}/..`)

const isDirectory = dirent => {
  return dirent instanceof fs.Dirent ? dirent.isDirectory() : false
}

const readDir = path => () => {
  return fs.readdirSync(path, { withFileTypes: true })
}

const leafs = nodePath => {
  return L.cond(
    [
      _.isArray,
      L.lazy(() => [
        L.elems,
        L.choose(({ name }) => leafs(path.join(nodePath, name)))
      ])
    ],
    [
      isDirectory,
      L.lazy(() => [
        readDir(nodePath),
        L.elems,
        L.choose(({ name }) => leafs(path.join(nodePath, name)))
      ])
    ],
    [L.identity]
  )
}

const listFiles = async () =>
  L.collect(
    leafs(basePath),
    fs.readdirSync(basePath, { withFileTypes: true })
  )
```

Comment: There is no need to use Lodash here. You can replace that dependency by switching `_.isArray` to `Array.isArray`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an interesting question in the sense that Partial Lenses can work on
asynchronous problems like this, but the library currently only provides a
little bit of direct support for asynchronous operations out-of-the-box.  In the
future the library could certainly be extended to provide more support for
performing asynchronous operations.

Traversals in Partial Lenses build
[applicative](https://wiki.haskell.org/Applicative_functor) operations.  By
using different applicatives different kinds of operations, like collecting
elements, computing a minimum of elements, or computing a new version of the
data structure, can be performed.

Many operations, like collecting elements or computing minimums, have an
underlying [monoid](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monoid).  Any monoid, like array
concatenation

```
const ConcatArray = {empty: () => [], concat: (l, r) => l.concat(r)}
```

can be converted to an applicative.  In Partial Lenses the
[`L.concat`](https://github.com/calmm-js/partial.lenses/#l-concat) and
[`L.concatAs`](https://github.com/calmm-js/partial.lenses/#l-concatas)
operations do that internally.

So, for collecting elements asynchronously, we could use an asynchronous version
of a concatenating monoid.  We can get there by creating a function that
converts any monoid to an asynchronous monoid:

```
const asyncMonoid = m => ({
  empty: async () => m.empty(),
  concat: async (l, r) => m.concat(await l, await r)
})
```

We can now define an asynchronous version of
[`L.collect`](https://github.com/calmm-js/partial.lenses/#l-collect) as follows:

```
const collectAsync = L.concatAs(
  async x => [x],
  asyncMonoid(ConcatArray)
)
```

One more thing we need for solving this problem is a way to get the result of an
asynchronous operation so that we can zoom into it using optics.  For that we
could define a new [primitive optic
function](https://github.com/calmm-js/partial.lenses/#l-tofunction) that awaits
for the focus before passing it forward in the optic composition:

```
const awaitIt = async (x, i, F, xi2yF) => xi2yF(await x, i)
```

Using the above `awaitIt` optic, we can now define asynchronous traversals over
the files in a file system given a suitable asynchronous `readDirectory`
function:

```
const filesUnderEntries = L.lazy(() => [
  awaitIt,
  L.elems,
  L.ifElse(L.get('isDir'), ['path', filesUnderDirectory], 'path')
])

const filesUnderDirectory = [L.reread(readDirectory), filesUnderEntries]
```

We can use the above traversals to examine a directory structure and select
files from under it.  We can also further compose operations to read those files
and examine data from those files.  For example

```
collectAsync(
  [
    filesUnderDirectory,
    L.when(R.test(/\.my$/)),
    L.reread(readFile),
    awaitIt
  ]
)
```

defines an asynchronous operation that traverses a directory tree and produces
the contents of files with the `.my` extension under the directory tree.

Here is a [playground with full code and examples using faked file system
operations](https://calmm-js.github.io/partial.lenses/playground.html#PTAEBUAsEsGdTqAhqAZkg1gU1AdwE5IAORW+aA9uarAHT5ZIAmT0+AgrAJ4B2AxgCg+FHrAAuoBswAibLHzFUuoALzJu-UESRjIqgHygA3gKS4k0CTyy5QABXwUAtnCwAKBrAoAbAG44VQ1gsMXBoJywKAFcxDywvPywAGlAARgAGdIBKLKERcVAsHjF8aHjVYwFUCgoALlAAbSMeJAj6gHIAIyR8Wi5o9oBfFObWrA7ugC92lLhZfHqSqKxBgF0kgXbqimAp9vqmlrbQdu8fWicuIZGj8ZPu7xmEWHn61LWNrZrdpEmfx4Oo2O7VgSGKSAuVzWAkGDW0ulWAhAoAA6jgnMRQLocEUSmV4IpQMJwdAeFodJB4IRseRdGDQAArKIFW6wAQMMRRfBkgBKF2IbgEbiByWe80GWQMoGF8Mg9VloAA1CdgO0laBbrMXmx6gBCXVzNgSja40rxAS5QYCJFgKCIRAodDYPCEEhkSjUOhSJgAMWg3iwnF4gmJBW9foDFSQGj45N0UpMZgsVhs9kcLmCcQS-ilwVC4UiMSzPn8KQy2VyoYkqH95TUJgARNsfr1+lEG-UG1AcN1W9E0LWiSIxLi6A2Nk3vlNgGdvJCO6Au5AcLPIQPI8SR8UxxPm9OHsBQeD553u6Aj2IIZd1zhN6PaOOYeyQlyyTWA7A4RTEVabaAALSAaAADKUQkFQEjRsGQ7eAGCjWsidrwMS-j4GI8AoG4MaQI4PDRLAkpOCIFDQEwWIUMgZJQZoRF4aRtB5KIkExgAssRpEVE4UrCgIWBOEQYhcPU1Gxm4kqBKATi0HxAlcGJGzEnwOjCTG0reCk+DiYYUmKTobhJpYoDqcg5iGZpMK5H+SHPOe4REJGPSEMoulbjopIAOaSexTC0KAaYUJ0AZcYgdJiH+uiIAGzAEhRACOUTMNS0CxrgVAFEpwRaGQ1T4Bi-BYL5oAAJISKlUTeGRnRYH+VViCOtIUcyOD0lgqA1nwZTFEO-A6EUSCBTgAAycASEwOgoOI+BRAoXIFYxBQAMIiEpYjsPgTkVEYMmCfUfJIN45hcLAbgNKsWQpC5u20C5v7ImiRL0nhthMK1pLNVRqmobA0AiKAFCoKAAAGwiwfIYiA7U80SCDcGrapaiDddy06JwgoiaAAAeUoNBj6ymKx3luEtPWretSBcLklmITAGG2fxkYUAJyVYpAOjqLAUQRASy6UHwzKSeToBVcgWjpq4f5gmRBnoR6CASFVOU4NosDfTwnmGYS2IalgGMSIzYjJQxVYmcmJVRqpbgY7MKQ+ikGPQAATFwPpaZjjvO-ppkSFbCBU2AgH-hAhBfR5IslFgOD-TebJWcHZDBPA77lOIPQG2raDpiL3gjX9AOmviRnQM6HKvlglVcH+gPevMYNKIDyCdBQ-hG-k1a1rAACqPAvfgACixRmvACO0N4vxyWJ2OmF7JUbIjWBBbAs+0NAqC994maI+5IRuO0hr4O052NO0spPEnnfd2QNcKEo6wnCfuRnQhtpx-gCfR+el5oaHqCZygrAMNffAyhZQtyYtHLuPcr6KCARUBoiMGDejiDIOQgCKYpDPhAsg-c8TxERH+AOoBe4Y1aPZc0f4AByFARwszZlrTw5UZYYmUMQUgPQ-oxFzn9fAPd1As0jqQJK+RkAMHUMGHCxFmQMQEGcdygoYZgyDPwQUGCL74CgUoT42x2gWh0dIigsi8igwUIovggoGhVHbpgtRKDoFcCXrgZcPA3B8hHOINwwAAA6kIAAkwAcgCDxl8Cg2jKbWhkXInwsMTFmIsR+Kx6igH2Mcc42grjYieJ8X486Ah4FkEYEwJBvpazZOliVAJmiaghN0eEnJqTCCiByk4aJsT4jxJsRozYWidFZCAA).